# SQL - Splitting / Prorating a metric

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table where a household ID can have multiple customer ID's. But revenue is linked to household ID. So when looking at the table with both household ID and customer ID, revenue is double counted. Sample below.

HHID 123 has 3 customers, total revenue is only $900 for the household but if I sum grouped by HHID, it's $2700. Similarly, HHID 456 has 2 customers and HHID 789 has 1.

How do I create a column to split this revenue per customer ID. I can do this in multiple steps but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in one query.

```
HH ID        CUST ID          REVENUE        NEW_COL
123          5655             $900           $300
123          6678             $900           $300
123          8893             $900           $300
789          8988             $350           $350
456          2343             $400           $200
456          4555             $400           $200
```

I need the table to have both HH ID and CUST ID since some metrics are based on HH and some based on CUST (such as age). So I need to add a column like the above to the table so I can use it to sum revenue instead of the actual revenue column.

I'm on Teradata.

Comment: Why do you need to sum the revenue? Can't you simply max/min/avg it?

Comment: I put the output into a pivot table in excel so I need to be able to slice as needed.

Comment: And how do you deal with a revenue of $800 and 3 Customers? Is the last dollar important, or is $233, $233, $233 satisfactory?

Comment: it's a split so $800/3 will be $266.66. The last dollar is not really important I'm not sure how you can drop the last dollar if the computation is a division.